# php date to python datetime port issues

Tags: php, python, django, datetime

We are currently porting some php scripts that are pulling datetimes from the facebook API and storing them in a mysql datetime column over to python.  However, when we pull the times from the mysql database, the times that were submitted in python are 6 hours later than the times submitted by the php scripts.  We are using the same python script to pull and display the values (it's a django app).  So there must be something going on when we are pushing the data into the mysql database.

the updated_time string would be in the following format: "2012-03-15T21:02:50+0000"

php:

```
$time = $status['updated_time'];
$time = strtotime($time);
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
```

python:

```
timestamp = datetime.strptime(status['updated_time'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S+0000")
```

I've also tried using the python-dateutil module to capture the timezone data and I get the same results.

I'm not sure if django is modifying the value or what.  It's super confusing to me.

Comment: are both your python and php scripts running on the same machine?

Comment: EST is +6 from GMT...  Check time zones

Comment: The php script was running on a different server, however, both servers have been set to Mountain Standard Time.  Server config was my first guess as well, I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason is timezone, the php `date()` function display local time,
while python `time.strftime()` fill an object

Try this php code (replace `date` with `gmdate`):

```
$time = $status['updated_time'];
$time = strtotime($time);
$time = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
```

and you should have same result